# ASP.NET MVC, Cache individual User Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

How do I cache an individual user control with ASP.NET **MVC**? I also need the VaryByParam etc support that usually comes with ASPX Output Caching. I don't want to cache the entire action though, only one of my user controls in the view.

An example would be nice :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phil Haack has written good article about that , it's called dnout hole caching http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx

Comment: the correct link is http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx